# How do I wait until data from Preferences DataStore is loaded?

Tags: android, kotlin, libgdx, datastore, kotlin-flow

I'm trying to make a LibGDX Live Wallpaper. But I think that is unrelated to the problem I'm having at the moment. Basically, I'm storing the wallpaper's settings inside a Preferences DataStore. Now, if you need to retrieve data from the DataStore, you need to retrieve a Kotlin `Flow` and use it to get the preferences. Inside LibGDX's `ApplicationListener` inside the `onCreate()` method, I need to create a KtxScreen object. I decided to pass all the preferences inside a constructor of my `Screen`. However, since a `Flow`'s data can only be obtained inside a coroutine, I cannot construct my `KtxScreen` object with the user preferences as a constructor parameter because I need to wait until my `Flow` emits the values. I solved this with a very very dirty `while (userPreferences == null) Unit` piece of code which basically blocks the whole app until the preferences are emitted so I can construct my `KtxScreen`. What would be a good way to solve this?

Comment: have you read the documentations? you can get the data in synchronous with `runBlocking`. i.e. `val exampleData = runBlocking { context.dataStore.data.first() }`. reference: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#synchronous

Comment: DataStore is an asynchronous api, you need to think about your architecture based on that fact. `runBlocking` also freezes the app.

Comment: @Sergey It won't freeze the app if called on an OpenGL rendering thread.

Comment: Right, I meant an app can freeze if call `runBlocking` on the Main Thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is acceptable in libGDX to block the rendering thread. This is a separate thread from the Android main thread, so it won't freeze the Android UI or put you at risk of an ANR (application not responding error). It will freeze any game/wallpaper rendering while blocking, but that's OK when you're still loading the scene.

So, it would be acceptable to use `runBlocking` in `create()` or `render()` to wait for the first batch of settings. Since KtxScreen doesn't use `create()`, you could block directly at the property initialization. You can call `first()` on a Flow to get just one item from it, which would be fine for initial setup of your KtxScreen class.

If you're using the `ktx-async` library from libKtx, you can collect your flow on the rendering thread, so then if the user updates the settings while your wallpaper is running, it will safely update your settings.

Here's one example of how you might achieve this (I didn't test it), but there are many acceptable different ways it could be handled. Note: this is assuming you instantiate this screen on the rendering thread, not the Android main thread. The rendering thread is what is used to call `create()` on your game class, which is the typical place to instantiate your first screen.

```
class MyScreen(
    val settingsFlow: Flow<UserPreferences>
): KtxScreen {

    var prefs: UserPreferences = runBlocking { settingsFlow.first() }

    init {
        settingsFlow
            .drop(1) // the first one should be the value we already got above
                     // unless the user changed them impossibly fast
            .onEach { prefs = it }
            .launchIn(KtxAsync)
    }

    //...
}
```

If you want to show some sort of initial loading image in your wallpaper, you could use if/else in your `render` function like this. But I don't think it should be necessary because preferences will take probably less than half a second to load.

```
class MyScreen(
    val settingsFlow: Flow<UserPreferences>
): KtxScreen {

    var _prefs: UserPreferences? = null

    init {
        settingsFlow
            .onEach { _prefs = it }
            .launchIn(KtxAsync)
    }

    override fun render() {
        val prefs = _prefs // for the sake of smart-casting
        if (prefs == null) {
            renderLoadingImage()
        } else {
            renderScene(prefs)
        }
    }

    //...

    private fun renderScene(prefs: UserPreferences) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this extensive explanation. I will implement everything from this post and report in a while if everything works.

Comment: I implemented everything (without the loading screen) and everything works just fine! Thank you again!

Comment: Also write the code snippet in java language.

Comment: @hasnain_ahmad This question is about Kotlin Flows and coroutines, which are not available in Java, so it doesn’t make sense to write a Java snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If we need to fetch the key value from Datastore as synchronous  way then we need to block the thread using runBlocking so that will return data in Primitive datatype.

```
fun getValue(context: Context): Int {

    return runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
    context.dataStore.dataStore.data.first()[EXAMPLE_COUNTER] ?: 0

}}
```

Incase to fetch value from Datastore as Asynchronous way then directly call map method which will return Flow.

```
fun <T> DataStore<Preferences>.getValueFlow(
key: Preferences.Key<T>,
defaultValue: T ): Flow<T> {
return this.data
    .catch { exception ->
        if (exception is IOException) {
            emit(emptyPreferences())
        } else {
            throw exception
        }}.map { preferences ->
        preferences[key] ?: defaultValue
    }}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Also write the code snippet in java language.